# Importing custom class in another .py file

Tags: python, python-import

I am facing a problem related to a python repository that I imported.

```
https://github.com/nav74neet/gail_gym.git
```

In `gail-ppo-tf-gym` folder, I need to run `run_ppo.py` file. This file has some dependencies related to the custom class in folder `network_models`. When I am trying to run the code, unfortunately, I am getting an error `'unresolved references'`.

I don't have a clue why I am facing this problem. Do I have to install some environment to run this code.

Please help me with this. It would be a great help and good learning for me. Also, apologies if I term something incorrectly as I am still in the learning phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read on [README file](https://github.com/nav74neet/gail_gym/blob/master/README.md) you've got some dependencies:

- python 3.5.2
- tensorflow 1.1.0
- gym 0.9.0

So you have to download them before to run the script. Follow these instructions for installation: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/ https://www.tensorflow.org/install https://github.com/openai/gym#id5

Tips: Use a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) inside your folder: a virtual environment for installing all your dependencies with the selected versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually, It was my bad. I used Pycharm to just open the project folder and not create the project. As a result, custom libs did not install. Thanks again for sparing time for this.

Comment: I don't know how Pycharm import modules works, so I found https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/guide/tips/install-and-import/. Maybe it could be helpful. Anyway, my pleasure :)